# Dark side of the self-inverse permutation

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, permutations, recurrences

- Let
  $$
  \ell(n) = \left\lfloor\log_2 n\right\rfloor
  $$
- Let
  $$
  f(n) = 2^{\ell(n)}
  $$
- Let $p_1(n)$ be an arbitrary self-inverse permutation of the non-negative integers such that $p_1(n)<2^k$ iff $n<2^k$.
- Let $s_1(n)$ and $s_2(n)$ be *light-to-dark* permutations of the nonnegative integers such that $s_1(s_2(n))=s_2(s_1(n))=n$, $s_i(n)<2^k$ iff $n<2^k$ and
  $$
  s_1(n) = s_1(p_1(n)-f(n))+f(n), \\
  s_1(0) = 0, \\
  s_2(n) = p_1(s_2(n-f(n))+f(n)), \\
  s_2(n) = 0
  $$
- Let $q_1(n)$ be *dark side* of the $p_1(n)$. Here
  $$
  q_1(n) = s_1(p_1(s_2(q_1(n-f(n)))) + f(n)), \\
  q_1(0) = 0
  $$

I conjecture that $q_1(n)$ is a self-inverse permutation.

I also conjecture that dark side of $q_1(n)$ is $p_1(n)$.

Here is the PARI/GP prog to check it numerically:

```
bc(n) = if(n == 0, 0, 3*2^logint(n, 2) - n - 1) \\ A054429 (s)
b1(n) = if(n == 0, 0, my(A = 2^logint(n, 2)); b1(bc(n) - A) + A)
b2(n) = if(n == 0, 0, my(A = 2^logint(n, 2)); while(!(b1(A) == n), A++); A)
b3(n) = if(n == 0, 0, my(A = 2^logint(n, 2)); b1(bc(b2(b3(n - A))) + A))
test(n) = b3(b3(n)) == n
```

You can also check it on other self-inverse permutations:

```
br(n) = if(n == 0, 0, my(A = binary(n)); fromdigits(concat(1, Vecrev(vector(#A - 1, i, A[i+1]))), 2)) \\ A059893 (s)
bcr(n) = if(n == 0, 0, my(A = binary(n)); fromdigits(concat(1, Vecrev(vector(#A - 1, i, 1 - A[i+1]))), 2)) \\ A059894 (s)
bb1(n) = if(n < 2, n, n + (-1)^n) \\ A065190 (s)
bb2(n) = if(n == 0, 0, {pow2=2; v=binary(n); L=#v-1; forstep(k=L, 2, -1, if(v[k], n-=pow2, n+=pow2); pow2*=2); return(n)};) \\ A092569 (s)
bb3(n) = if(n<2, n, bitxor(n, 1<<(logint(n, 2)-1))); \\ A063946 (s)
bb4(n) = { my (v=0); forstep (x=#binary(n)-1, 0, -1, if (bittest(n, x), v+=2^x; ); n=bitxor(n, n\2)); return (v) } \\ A334727 (s)
bb5(n) = if(n, bitxor(n, 2<<logint(n, 2)\3), 0); \\ A165199 (s)
bb6(n) = my(b=binary(n), k); if (#b%2, k=#b\2+2, k=#b/2+1); for (i=k, #b, b[i]=1-b[i]); fromdigits(b, 2); \\ A080261 (s)
bb7(n)={local(x='x); subst(lift(Mod(1, 2)*subst(Pol(binary(n), x), x, 1+x)), x, 2)}; \\ A193231 (s)
```

---

**UPD**:

If $p_1(n)$ is not a self-inverse permutation, I conjecture that $q_1(n)$ is also not a self-inverse permutation.

I also conjecture that we have

$$
s_1(n) = s_1(p_1(n)-f(n))+f(n), \\
s_1(0) = 0, \\
s_2(n) = p_2(s_2(n-f(n))+f(n)), \\
s_2(n) = 0, \\
s_1(n) = q_1(s_1(n-f(n))+f(n)), \\
s_1(n) = 0, \\
s_2(n) = s_2(q_2(n)-f(n))+f(n), \\
s_2(0) = 0, \\
$$
Here $p_1(p_2(n)) = p_2(p_1(n)) = n$ and $q_1(q_2(n)) = q_2(q_1(n)) = n$. Also, we have
$$
q_1(n) = s_1(p_2(s_2(q_1(n-f(n)))) + f(n)), \\
q_1(0) = 0
$$
It remains an open problem whether one could find similar recursive way to compute $q_2(n)$ (alternative to finding it as inverse permutation) when $p_1(n)$ and $p_2(n)$ (and $q_1(n)$, if necessary) is known.

---

Is there a way to prove it? Is there a recursive way to compute $q_2(n)$ (alternative to finding it as inverse permutation)?